# gapless looping audio html5

Tags: javascript, html, audio

anyone have any idea how to accomplish gapless looping for the audio tag? I'm thinking something javascript based..

I have a loop say 1 measure and I want it to loop and stay in tempo. So I need the loop to be smooth/gapless. When i simply set "loop" to true it will lag and does not stay in tempo.

Comment: Might be possible, although .ogg files (I think) have a set frame time, so you will always get a delay unless the sample is the perfect length. What's this for, just out of interest?

Comment: made a sort of drum machine that automagically generates a wav file from an array of notes (start times). the sample is (should be) the exact length of the loop.. when i import into Audacity and loop it there it's seamless.

Comment: Sounds like a neat project. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I doubt browsers can do that, except possibly some fiddling in the Firefox audio API

Comment: I've tried 2 audio elements and when one ends the other starts. Which I thought might help, however there is still a delay. Could offset the delay by starting the next loop half a second early.. But that only works if the delay is exactly .5 seconds long, which it isn't..

Comment: I should add that I'm really trying to stay clear of Flash. I could probably achieve this with Flash, but it's 2011.

Comment: @ndmweb And now it's 2013, and it's still a problem. Sigh.

Comment: 2015 here. Flash is still a problem, but not as much as the end is in sight!

Comment: @PeterT Can you show an example for this?

Comment: @Marimba -- I deleted my response: I thought I had double buffering on timeouts working but the buffers still kept drifting. It turns out my scheme of scheduling a new buffer on completion still is subject to system latency. Oops. I then tried a WebWorker and -that- scheme can't accept AudioContexts (feh). So now there is an AudioWorklet (!) -- https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioWorklet  --- Good luck, sorry for getting your hopes up.

Comment: @PeterT Not sure about the context now. But in the meantime I got a seamless loop working with the Web Audio Api (loop Attribute on an AudioBufferSourceNode)

Comment: @Marima -- in my case i'm creating a waveform dynamically so I cannot use the loop API call: I have to constantly build the next buffer with new (varying) data. but now i'm digressing from the original thread... glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately this is one of the weaknesses of the HTML5  element.  There is no guarantee that audio will play when you want it to or without delay.

There are two options worth looking into:

1. [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) - a great library that would probably be helpful here, though it'll use Flash to play the audio in this case;
2. **Web Audio API** in Chrome or the **Audio Data API** in Firefox - both are really new, and not really ready for prime time yet, but allow you to do things like scheduled audio playback, looping and a whole lot more.

Comment: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#EventScheduling-section          Yep the Audio API is what I was after. Seems they are still hammering out the details, but you can play with it in chrome and webkit with some hackery.

Comment: The newest webaudio api is: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/

Answer (score 54):

While still not perfect, this worked for me:

```
var audio_file = new Audio('whatever.mp3')
audio_file.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
    var buffer = .44
    if(this.currentTime > this.duration - buffer){
        this.currentTime = 0
        this.play()
    }
});
```

Experiment with the size of the buffer to find what works best for you

Comment: Your example worked by far the best. I have tried two libraries: Gapless5 and Seamless.js.  Gapless uses web audio then HTML5 as a fallback, so it does not work on everything. Seamless has a buffering concept, but I could only get it to work on Chrome. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thank you for the working snippet @shooting_sparks! Is there a way to understand what is the exact value for buffer? Thanks

Comment: This is a great idea - thanks for posting. Still have IE11 to worry about, after all.

Comment: I didn't get this to work this the .44 buffer and I'm still playing around with it. How do I get the perfect value?

Comment: Thanks, that's works perfect in Chrome, Opera, and Edge. But not in Firefox. I've no idea why is that

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, but I had to play the audio first so it would trigger the "timeupdate" listener. Great work around!

Comment: building a web drum sequencer, tried this idea, changed the buffer to .25 vs .44 it worked better for me (my drum sequencer also uses time update event listener to light up the blocks / pads with the beat, and I am using the 250ms resolution limit of the browser, and noticed .25 allowed my pads to still light up but .44 the last pads didn't, and also it loops alot better) - I think Firefox has a different way it checks for time update vs chrome based, I read it does it via frames vs the 250 ms frequency that chrome does. (works with 120bpm beats right now, testing other bopms) Thanks! Jeff

Comment: I couldn't get a perfect loop with either .44 or .25 or smaller numbers. It either cuts the end of the sound or leaves a smaller gap. I'm guessing, from the other comments, this gap might be performance-based, so... kinda stuck anyway.

Comment: Has anyone managed to make it work with Safari? I tried this approach and it works on Chrome and Firefox but not Safari.

Comment: Had to adjust syntax for modern Typescript Angular framework but, yes, this solution was the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Solution is to have 2 instances to control the play back.

Something like this :

```
var current_player = "a";
var player_a = document.createElement("audio");
var player_b = document.createElement("audio");

player_a.src = "sounds/back_music.ogg";
player_b.src = player_a.src;

function loopIt(){
    var player = null;

    if(current_player == "a"){
        player = player_b;
        current_player = "b";
    }
    else{
        player = player_a;
        current_player = "a";
    }

    player.play();

    setTimeout(loopIt, 5333); //5333 is the length of the audio clip in milliseconds.
}

loopIt();
```

And if you're using SoundManager2, source the audio through a Data URI instead of an URL request.

Strangely, I found that SoundManager2 request the file from the server each time it plays. Even it's loading from the cache, there will be a delay until the not-modified header is received for the audio file.

Comment: This is not an effective method, as milliseconds in browsers are not consistent or granular enough. You will experience lag if the browser is slowing down due to process load, or for round off errors.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I tend to agree with xHocquet but your solution is possibly workable for ambient, pad, or white/pink noise sounds with a short fade-in and fade out. I suspect it may still glitch in a way that isn't controllable even under these circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, this is a real pain... evidently whoever spec'd out the  element wasn't either a musician or game developer - heh.

Anyhow, depending on what you're doing, another possible workaround is to create an MP3/OGG/wav that is several repeats of your loop long. This comes in handy for where you want to loop a sound only a few times before you stop playing it.

An example of this might be a player thrusting in a rocket ship. I'm developing a game at the moment with just this scenario and have created an MP3 with a number of loops of the thrust sound effect, totalling about 6 seconds of playback. In order to minimise the size of the download I've encoded the audio at 32kbps - any lower and it starts to sound unacceptably splashy, since the thrust sound is largely white noise.

As you can guess, I'm just banking on the fact that it's very unlikely a player would thrust continuously for 6 seconds. If they do, they'll hear the gap, but I can live with that. Most of the time they won't thrust for anything like that long, so won't hear the glitch.

Another option I've considered is a pair of samples that fade in and out and both loop with an offset.

Whilst these work for the some game scenarios they almost certainly wouldn't work for any kind of music scenario. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried the methods above without success, In my use case (using Firefox 43.0) all seem to click. This is due in part to having to loop a continous tone which has no handy breaks or low points in it (I'm trying to create a reving car engine using 22010 samples/sec mono .wav files).

However I am able to concatinate my .wav file together multiple times to generate a single long .wav file which has no clicks in it (except the now infrequent one that still occurs at the end), this is because my original .wav file was carefully crafted to be cyclic.

I now plan to have several of these long files all playing continously at the same time (one for each car rpm level) and mix these signals using a gainNode (described here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/). This should result in a click free car engine that will sound much better than simply starting and stopping the individual .wav files from playing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet possible using HTML5 audio because the ended event triggers only once per audio item.

Answer (score 0):

my approach is a daunting one, but the one that works for ambient background music

let's say our track has 5.3 seconds

you have 2 audio tracks of the same file. when is one about to end (for example 1 second before ending - 4.3s-5.3s ) you fade it out (set volume by percent of position within this one second). at the same time,  the second track starts fading in (0s-1s). you can do it via some 50ms interval, or something else, depending on your audio library

after the playback ends you switch a boolean variable that controls this fadein/fadeout and reverse which track will fade in and which track will fade out in the next run

Comment: A html5 web audio gainNode could be used to do the fade in/out.