# Seamless audio loop to an arbitrary position

Tags: html, html5-audio

One of the things I most love about the MOD format is the ability to loop back to any given point in the song, making it perfect for songs that have an "intro" followed by a "main loop".

Of course, MP3 can't do this.

Up until now, I've done things like this:

```
<audio src="/path/to/song.mp3" onEnded="this.currentTime = 12.345;"></audio>
```

Where the float value is the time at which the main loop starts.

While this works there is a noticeable fraction-of-a-second pause as the audio restarts. I can lessen the effect of this pause by setting the target time a little ahead of where it should be, so the beats are at least kept closer in time, however it's not really ideal.

The main alternative I can think of is to manually loop the audio file (eg. in Audacity by copy-pasting) to produce a song that is longer than it would most likely be needed for, but the problem with that is that it would result in a lot of wasted hard drive space and bandwidth, and it wouldn't solve the problem of people liking a song and stopping to listen to it for a long time.

So I was wondering if there's any way to loop an MP3 stream. If I understand the format correctly, I should be able to determine at what position in the file (in bytes) the main loop starts (in seconds), so in theory I could construct a stream that loops indefinitely. However, would such a stream be supported by HTM5 audio?

Comment: have you seen [this site on gapless looping?](http://www.compuphase.com/mp3/mp3loops.htm)  It doesn't cover html5, but it does talk about the theory of what needs to be in the mp3 file to have a chance of looping.

Comment: @AShelly While that's interesting, it only really applies to files that are to be looped back to the beginning, not to an arbitrary point.

Comment: Just thought I should point this other SO question out: [Looping Audio HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330023/gapless-looping-audio-html5)

Comment: @Kolink If I'm not mistaken, it also applies to loops that extend to the end of the track. Due to the fact that the last frame has to be a multiple of a fixed number of samples and is therefore padded with silence. If this applies to your case, padding/offsetting the beggining could help fill the last frame.

Comment: +1 for the reference to MOD :D Nostalgia creeps under my skin...

Answer (score 1):

Try measuring the delay each time:

```
function playSeamless(clip, next) {
    if(!next) {
        next = clip.cloneNode(true);
        next.controls = false;
    }

    var start = Date.now();
    clip.play();

    setTimeout(function() {
        var time = (Date.now() - start) / 1000;
        var position = clip.currentTime;
        var delay = time - position;

        setTimeout(function() {
            // Set desired currentTime on next here and adjust delay above
            playSeamless(next, clip);
        }, (clip.duration - clip.currentTime - delay * 2.35) * 1000 | 0);
    }, 200);
}

playSeamless(yourAudioClip);
```

It was better, but not entirely accurate, so I need to adjust `* 2.35` or make it a subtraction or something.

Comment: SeamlessLoop uses similar strategy. Found this on net https://github.com/Hivenfour/SeamlessLoop/blob/master/SeamlessLoop.js.