# html5 audio loop from point a to b

Tags: javascript, html, audio

according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/),

html5 audio has the following properties:

**loop**
Indicates if the audio data should play in a loop. The default value is false.

**loopStart**
An optional value in seconds where looping should begin if the loop attribute is true. Its default value is 0, and it may usefully be set to any value between 0 and the duration of the buffer.

**loopEnd**
An optional value in seconds where looping should end if the loop attribute is true. Its default value is 0, and it may usefully be set to any value between 0 and the duration of the buffer.

I am trying to loop a segment of an audio file, from second 5 to 8 for example.

I have tried many combinations, including with/without using:
 #t= url param  | 
loopstart/loopend attributes in the DOM  | 
loop attribute

Nothing works so far (chrome browser). Perhaps theese properties are simply not supported yet. I am trying to avoid using javascript to set the currenttime of the audio.

**HTML**

```
<audio controls="" src="http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/tail%20toddle.mp3#t=5,8"        loopstart="5" loopend="8" loop></audio>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var myAudio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
myAudio.loopStart = 5;
myAudio.loopEnd = 8;
myAudio.play();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsKMJ/1/)

I have looked at:
[Seamless audio loop to an arbitrary position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152035/seamless-audio-loop-to-an-arbitrary-position)
and
[gapless looping audio html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330023/gapless-looping-audio-html5)

Comment: For all audio operations which are more complex than simple play/stop try Web Audio API instead of <audio> element as it is more powerful and well-defined http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Comment: Indeed, I was just reading up on that. amazing stuff. from what I read far, the web audio api uses ajax to load audio resources. this limits us to use resources on same domain or with coors support.

Comment: As far as I know <audio> is subject to the same CORS restrictions.

Comment: <audio> works with src attribute that may be set to a different domain, just like an iframe's src. but audiocontext uses ajax and is therefore more limited. for example, http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg can be loaded with <audio> but not with XMLHttpRequest for audiocontext

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

**JS**

```
function audio() {
if (document.getElementById("music").currentTime >= 8) {document.getElementById("music").currentTime = 5}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<audio id="music" controls ontimeupdate="audio()">
<source src="http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/tail%20toddle.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<audio>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this answers the question?

Comment: Whenever 'ontimeupdate' is called, it calls the function "audio()" which will automatically reset the audio to 5. This loops between a fix point (5 to 8). You could re-write this so that the 8 and 5 are replaced by variables 

If you want jquery it could be ---- $("#music").bind('timeupdate', audio);

Answer (score 0):

Cut your audio file past that time.