# Create Seamless Loop of Audio - Web

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I want to create a seamless loop of an audio file. But in all approaches I used so far, there was a noticeable gap between end & start.

---

**This is what I tried so far:**

First approach was to use the audio in the HTML and it loops but there is still a noticeable delay when going from the end of the track to the beginning.

```
<audio loop autoplay>
    <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<audio>
```

Then I tried it from JavaScript with the same result:

```
let myAudio = new Audio(file);
myAudio.loop = true; 
myAudio.play();
```

After that I tried this (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22446616/5504438))

```
myAudio.addEventListener(
    'timeupdate',
    function() {
        var buffer = .44;
        if (this.currentTime > this.duration - buffer) {
            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.play();
        }
     },
     false
);
```

I played around with the buffer but I only got it to reduce the gap but not leave it out entirely.

I turned to the library `SeamlessLoop` ([GitHub](https://github.com/Hivenfour/SeamlessLoop)) and got it to work to loop seamlessly in Chromium browsers (but not in the latest Safari. Didn't test in other browsers). Code I used for that:

```
let loop = new SeamlessLoop();
// My File is 58 Seconds long. Btw there aren't any gaps in the file.
loop.addUri(file, 58000, 'sound1');
loop.callback(soundsLoaded);
function soundsLoaded() {
    let n = 1;
    loop.start('sound' + n);
}
```

**EDIT:** I tried another approach: Looping it trough two different audio elements:

```
var current_player = "a";
var player_a = document.createElement("audio");
var player_b = document.createElement("audio");

player_a.src = "sounds/back_music.ogg";
player_b.src = player_a.src;

function loopIt(){
    var player = null;

    if(current_player == "a"){
        player = player_b;
        current_player = "b";
    }
    else{
        player = player_a;
        current_player = "a";
    }

    player.play();

    /*
        3104.897 is the length of the audio clip in milliseconds.
        Received from player.duration. 
        This is a different file than the first one
    */
    setTimeout(loopIt, 3104.897); 
}

loopIt();
```

But as milliseconds in browsers are not consistent or granular enough this doesn't work too well but it does work much better than the normal "loop" property of the audio.

---

Can anyone guide me into the right direction to loop the audio seamlessly?

Comment: Tried it today with a different file with the format wav aswell. No gaps at the end/start of the file. Still a noticeable delay.

Comment: Checked again if the file really has no gaps. And it doesn't. I played it in a audio player and looped it there and the transition is very seamless.

Comment: What can I improve in the question?

Comment: *"Checked again if the file really has no gaps. And it doesn't. I played it in a audio player and looped it there and the transition is very seamless."* I'm confused...does that mean you resolved the issue already?

Comment: @zer00ne I meant that the transition is very seamless in the audio player (like Windows Media Player / iTunes) but not in the browser.

Comment: Ok, post a real audio file you want to use, I don't want to do any editing of a mp3 or wav file and then get conflicting results.

Comment: @zer00ne Okay will do. Where should I upload it?

Comment: [Vocaroo,com](http://vocaroo.com/) will make an upload playable by browser, but getting that url isn't obvious. So after upload is completed, find a link that says `mp3` and right click it. Next `copy url address`.  if done successfully, the url that you paste from the clipboard should play from the browser rather than downlod.

Comment: @zer00ne you can get the file from here: https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rlnuc7j8afo6d2a/test2.wav?dl=0

Comment: AFAIK mp3 files are never gapless. Have you tried your two audio elements approach with a wav or a flac file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) instead. There are a couple of caveats with this, but it will allow you to loop accurately down to the single sample level.

The caveats are that you have to load the entire file into memory. This may not be practical with large files. If the files are only a few seconds it should however not be any problem.

The second is that you have to write control buttons manually (if needed) as the API has a low-level approach. This means play, pause/stop, mute, volume etc. Scanning and possibly pausing can be a challenge of their own.

And lastly, not all browsers [support Web Audio API](https://caniuse.com/#search=web%20audio%20api) - in this case you will have to fallback to the regular Audio API or even Flash, but if your target is modern browsers this should not be a major problem nowadays.

### Example

This will load a 4 bar drum-loop and play without any gap when looped. The main steps are:

- It loads the audio from a CORS enabled source (this is important, either use the same domain as your page or set up the external server to allow for cross-origin usage as Dropbox does for us in this example).
- AudioContext then decodes the loaded file
- The decoded file is used for the source node
- The source node is connected to an output
- Looping is enabled and the buffer is played from memory.

```js
var actx = new (AudioContext || webkitAudioContext)(),
    src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/fdcf2lwsa748qav/drum44.wav",
    audioData, srcNode;  // global so we can access them from handlers

// Load some audio (CORS need to be allowed or we won't be able to decode the data)
fetch(src, {mode: "cors"}).then(function(resp) {return resp.arrayBuffer()}).then(decode);

// Decode the audio file, then start the show
function decode(buffer) {
  actx.decodeAudioData(buffer, playLoop);
}

// Sets up a new source node as needed as stopping will render current invalid
function playLoop(abuffer) {
  if (!audioData) audioData = abuffer;  // create a reference for control buttons
  srcNode = actx.createBufferSource();  // create audio source
  srcNode.buffer = abuffer;             // use decoded buffer
  srcNode.connect(actx.destination);    // create output
  srcNode.loop = true;                  // takes care of perfect looping
  srcNode.start();                      // play...
}

// Simple example control
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  if (srcNode) {
    srcNode.stop();
    srcNode = null;   
    this.innerText = "Play";
  } else {
    playLoop(audioData);
    this.innerText = "Stop";
  }
};
```

```html
<button>Stop</button>
```

Comment: I'll try this out this evening. I have my own controls written anyway. 
Does this also work in mobile chrome / mobile safari?

Comment: @Marimba if the browsers support Web Audio API ([and they seem to be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API#Browser_compatibility) although with experimental status) it should work, however, there is always the risk of implementation errors in the particular versions so it has to be tested for each.

Comment: Okay, good. This works fine with your file. How did you get this kind of dropbox URL?

Comment: Also can you explain the syntax in the first line? (where you get the audioContext) (I got it working now with my file)

Comment: @Marimba the first line is because in webkit AudioContext may be prefixed. Using this syntax will do a logic or so if AudioContext doesn't exist it will try webkitAudioContext instead. Of course, in production you have to check the result of this ORing so that any lack of support at all can be caught.

Comment: @Marimba there is no convenient way to obtain the dropbox link afaik. I just replace the sub+domain manually to get a direct link to the resource.

Comment: For the dropbox link: That was easy. And in the first line I understand the webKitAudio / Audio Context thing. But not the src / srcNode and audioData declaration. I have never seen this kind of syntax before.

Comment: @Marimba ah, you mean the declarations? You can declare multiple values with a single var/let/const statement using comma. You can even break the line which eventually is terminated with a semi-column. They are also made global so they are accessible from with the handlers.

Comment: Would be the same like: ... var audioData; var srcNode; Right?

Comment: I experience quite high lags with this code on higher CPU usage. Isn't there a way that I can reserve enough CPU power for running this script so that there are no lags? (Lags in music is not exactly what I desire...)

Comment: @Marimba I would to see more details. This is extremely basic code and just playing audio takes very little resources, especially when the data already is decompressed to PCM ("raw") form - it basically feeds the buffer to the system audio driver with almost no overhead. I suspect something else goes on. Which browser would this be? Of course, if the CPU load is caused by something outside the browser (or some other tab/script) there is little we can do to affect how the browser will behave.

Comment: Chrome. It's from a program outside of the browser. (Visual Studio :))

Comment: @Marimba true, VS is a bit resource hungry :) I'm afraid you can't do much - Chrome (and FF) throttle tabs that are not active meaning the tabs don't get access to as much "cpu" as when they are active (affecting things frame-rate, video, audio etc.). We don't have direct access to do something about it.. :-/

Comment: On Windows I was able to set a higher priority for the process of my website. So far no lags but I need to test some more.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple solution for that, just use [loopify](https://github.com/veltman/loopify) it makes use of the html5 web audio api and works perfectly well with many formats, not only wav as the dev says.

```
<script src="loopify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    loopify("yourfile.mp3|ogg|webm|flac",ready);

    function ready(err,loop){
      if (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }

        loop.play();
    }
</script>
```

This will automatically play the file, if you want to have start and stop buttons for example take a look at his [demo](http://veltman.github.io/loopify/demo.html)

Comment: This does exactly the same thing in the background as the accepted answer.