# Javascript Playing BASE64 Audio Files Without Delay

Tags: javascript, html, function, audio

I wrote a very simple JavaScript file to play BASE64 Wav files.

I did not paste the encoded wav files becuase it's a HUGE string and it won't let me post it anyways but just for you to get the idea :

```
let whiteNoise=new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64, {{Here goes the BASE64 Wav encoded file of the white noise}} ");
let pinkNoise=new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64, {{Here goes the BASE64 Wav encoded file of the pink noise}} ");

whiteNoise.play();

whiteNoise.onended=function()
{
    pinkNoise.play();
};

pinkNoise.onended=function()
{
    whiteNoise.play();
};
```

It's working (almost) perfectly the only issue I got is that there is a tiny delay between then

```
[White Noise][***UNWANTER DELAY***][Pink Noise][***UNWANTER DELAY***] (etc...)
```

I Want to get

```
[White Noise][Pink Noise][White Noise][Pink Noise] (etc..)
```

So it would sound like 1 single endless file :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Seamless Loop of Audio - Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46926033/create-seamless-loop-of-audio-web)

Comment: No bro, I do not want to use any external resources :D

Comment: The Web Audio API (referenced in the accepted answer) is built into the browser...? Also, any requirements like that should be written into the question.