# Continuously play overlapping audio loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, audio, html5-audio

I want to continuously play audio in a loop, but each repetition is supposed to overlap with the previous one. Another button should be able to stop the loop.

This is what I tried:

- `var audio = new Audio(...` Create `audio`
- `audio.ontimeupdate = ...` Use `ontimeupdate` event to check if audio almost over
- `if (event.target.duration - event.target.currentTime <= 1 && audio == event.target) ...` Check if overlap is 1 second and make sure the event is triggered by the current `audio` (because `audio` will be overwritten, this is only supposed to trigger once per repetition)
- `audio = new Audio();` Discard the reference to the "old" (currently still playing the last second) `audio` and create a "new" `audio` instead, copying all relevant properties `src` and `ontimeupdate`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Audio loop</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<script>
var audio = new Audio("data:audio/mpeg;base64,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");
audio.ontimeupdate = function(event) {
  if (event.target.duration - event.target.currentTime <= 1 && audio == event.target) {
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = event.target.src;
    audio.ontimeupdate = event.target.ontimeupdate;
    audio.play();
  }
};
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function() {
  audio.play();
};
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function() {
  audio.pause();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the result of what you tried? - With the audio playing, I can't differentiate between expected result vs actual - although it seems like the original continues to play despite being unset and reset with a new src?

Comment: This might be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). What are you trying to accomplish here? Why not cut the audio file shorter to match the duration you want? When you chop off playing a file without a fadeout like this, you'll get clipping.

Comment: You might be looking for [gapless looping audio html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330023/gapless-looping-audio-html5)

Comment: @TCooper I apologize. Maybe it just sounds different on your browser? When I play my example, there is less than 1 second of overlap... which makes it sound weird

Comment: Also, I was wondering about memory issues. Do the previous instances (that I keep referencing) automatically get garbage collected?

Comment: @ggorlen I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I _do_ want the overlap. I want the audio to overlap with itself. For 1 second, there should be the ending and the beginning playing along each other.

Comment: OK, so you're OK with the volume doubling during the overlap time? The sine wave-based sample you're using here seems like it'll sound rather unpleasant if you do this as you're requesting. Yes, previous instances should be garbage collected when they're no longer referenced.

Comment: @ggorlen  Yes this audio is just an example of C, D, E sine waves, 1 second each. I'm okay with the "bad" sound. That's just part of this being a minimal example. But the timing is off, and that seems like a deeper issue. Also: you're saying that the instances will get garbage collected when no longer referenced, but am I not referencing them in every new instance by assigning `src` to the previous `src`, all the way to the very first instance?

Comment: It'll always be less than 1 second as it detects once it gets to one second, and while minimal, there is processing time. You may want to try two identical audio files playing on timers. Kind of a 'clumsy' solution, but should work as expected without concern for browser processing time differences (rather than trying to guess the .13 seconds or whatever the delay is)

Comment: Is the web audio API an option? If this is for an app that needs precise musical timing, and especially if you're playing synthesized notes, that's what I'd go for. I guess I'm still unclear as to why you need the overlap, hence the XY problem suggestion above.

Comment: @TCooper Hmm, true. "Clumsy" indeed but if it produces better results, not a bad idea. Also, in my browser, it's way more than 0.13 seconds, more than 0.5 seconds even. I think I might be okay with 0.13 second, although I expected it to be something like 10 milliseconds, not 13 times that... :( I'm a little disappointed in the responsiveness if that's as good as it gets. That's why I thought I'm probably just doing it wrong.

Comment: @rattlesnake I'm not sure the actual numbers, but I'd guess an event listener on an audio file is only checking the conditional once every 10ms or on some kind of similar delay.

Comment: From adding a quick `console.log(new Date());` above the conditional it actually looks like it's about 250ms between each check