# jquery Audio don't repeat

Tags: jquery, audio

I would like to repeat an audio file with 5 seconds length for example 10 times.

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sounds/test.mp3');
$('#play').click(function() {
    audioElement.play();
});
```

That is working fine. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cpmrqn4s/11/

**But:**
My app replay automatically the sound but with a small gap between.
So you have milliseconds without sound.

So 2 questions:

1. How can I stop the auto repeat?
2. And how can I make a loop of 10 times without a sound gap?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps use the `loop` property? https://jsfiddle.net/kfh3qybp/. There's no way for you to remove the few milliseconds of silence between each loop though - even the browser does it whenyou set `loop = true`. It's caused by the browser returning to the start of the file stream in order to read it again. There is a workaround you can use, detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22446616/519413). This uses the `timeupdate` event to manually return the audio to the start a short time before the file actually ends.

Comment: **(1)** _"How can I stop the auto repeat?"_ Remove `this.play();` in your **Ended** event. **(2)** If you want it to only stop after 10 plays then use a counter that adds `+1` at each Ended event and also add an **IF** to check if counter is 10 or higher, if not higher then do `play()`. **(3)** _"How to loop... without a sound gap?"_ Many options... Use a sound editor to trim at nearest to perfect end-point... Or read the file as bytes into a JS Array then select enough MP3 frames for one loop then copy/paste those bytes 10 times (makes Array longer) then use Array as source of `<audio>` tag.

Comment: Or convert MP3 to PCM (raw / uncompressed audio data) and then repeat the given PCM values for 10x (in Array). You can get PCM by using audio tag's `decodeAudio`... Or you could use Media Source Extensions (a decoder) to feed it the MP3 bytes. Feed for 10x to get 10 loops. Feeding is done via `appendBuffer( someMP3Array );`... Or check **currentTime** and set it to `0` when ready to re-loop. **PS:** How did you make the MP3 file? It has a 3:35 minute duration but cuts out at 3 seconds? Is that a bad file or intentional? Use Audacity or Goldwave if you need a free sound editor